# How to zoom only visible image in image view not transparent part of image?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uitapgesturerecognizer, pinchzoom

I have a scrollView in a UIView and a imageView in the ScrollView.scrollview and imageview have same size.I have set image view content mode is UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit . when i double tap on image view , image view not zoom only visible image of image view but also zoom transparent portion of image.

I want only zoom visible image of image view.

```
image_scroll = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,screen_width,550)];
self.image_view = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0, image_scroll.frame.size.width, image_scroll.frame.size.height)];
self.image_view.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
self.image_view.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
self.image_view.clipsToBounds = true;
self.image_view.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
self.image_view.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"img1.png"];
doubleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleDoubleTap:)];
[doubleTap setNumberOfTapsRequired:2];
[self.image_view addGestureRecognizer:doubleTap];
[image_scroll setMaximumZoomScale:4.0];
[image_scroll addSubview:self.image_view];


- (void)handleDoubleTap:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {

        NSLog(@"handleDoubleTap");

        float newScale = [image_scroll zoomScale] * 2.0;

        if (newScale > image_scroll.maximumZoomScale){
            newScale = image_scroll.minimumZoomScale;
            CGRect zoomRect = [self zoomRectForScale:newScale withCenter:[gestureRecognizer locationInView:gestureRecognizer.view]];

            [image_scroll zoomToRect:zoomRect animated:YES];

        }
        else{

            newScale = imageScroll.maximumZoomScale;
            CGRect zoomRect = [self zoomRectForScale:newScale withCenter:[gestureRecognizer locationInView:gestureRecognizer.view]];

            [image_scroll zoomToRect:zoomRect animated:YES];
        }
    }
}


- (CGRect)zoomRectForScale:(float)scale withCenter:(CGPoint)center {

    CGRect zoomRect;
    // the zoom rect is in the content view's coordinates.
    //    At a zoom scale of 1.0, it would be the size of the imageScrollView's bounds.
    //    As the zoom scale decreases, so more content is visible, the size of the rect grows.
    zoomRect.size.height = [image_scroll frame].size.height / scale;
    zoomRect.size.width  = [image_scroll frame].size.width  / scale;

    // choose an origin so as to get the right center.
    zoomRect.origin.x    = center.x - (zoomRect.size.width  / 2.0);
    zoomRect.origin.y    = center.y - (zoomRect.size.height / 2.0);

    return zoomRect;

}
```

1.Original image
[image]
2.After image zoom
[image]
[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am also getting this issue.

Answer (score 0):

## Objective-C

I think you should check for my demo project :
https://github.com/VivekVithlani/PinchZoom-Objective-c.git

I have not implement double tap to zoom, it's only pinch-zoom.

Your problem solved 100%